# Any trick to close all folder trees except the current one in Windows Explorer?

Tags: windows-explorer

I like to have the folder tree be updated to the current directory. As I jump around the computer to different drives and locations in Windows Explorer, the folder tree pane on the left becomes really long. This is because it has kept all the folder trees of all my previous locations open.

Is there a trick/keyboard shortcut/script to close all the expanded folder trees, except the tree of the currently open directory in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way I've found is to right click an empty area in the folder pane. If you won't right click anything, you'll get two options: Show all folders and Expand to current.

If you click Show all and then toggle it back, that usually clears most of them.  It won't collapse the my computer or network connections all the way however.

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to hack this into an AHK script?

Comment: It'll take some detective work, but I'm sure it's possible.